# Group by action and get rightdatime

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, grouping

I have a List ActionSchedule

```
public class ActionSchedule
{
    public TaskJob Mode {get;set}
    public TimeSpan Start {get;set}

    public DateTime ConvertToDatime(bool updatenextday = false)
    {
        DateTime result = DateTime.Today.Add(Start);

        if (updatenextday)
        {
            if (Start.Hours < dateTimeNow.Hour || (Start.Hours == dateTimeNow.Hour && Start.Minutes <= dateTimeNow.Minute))
                result = result.AddDays(1);
        }

        return result;
    }

} 

public enum TaskJob
    {
        Pause,
        Resume,
        Login,
        Close,
    }
```

Example list:

## gr1

Login 9:00
Pause 9:02
Resume 10:00
Close 15:00

## gr2

Login 17:00
Pause 18:00
Resume 18:30
Close 21:00

## gr3

Login 22:00
Close 06:00 (next day)

---

I need to get from this list Actions that start with Mode = Login ad finish with Mode = Close and the Start (TimeSpan) of Mode login > time.now and Start of mode Close < time now.

if datetime now is 10:00 it will give me gr1 list

if datetime now is 14:00 it will give me gr1 list

if datetime now is 16:00 it will give me gr2 list cause gr1 end at 15:00

if datetime now is 20:00 it will give me gr2

if datetime now is 23:00 it will give me gr3

if datetime now is 05:00 it will give me gr3

if datetime now is 07:00 it will give me gr1 cause gr3 was end at 06:00

Thanks for help.

Comment: it does not seem like a group. can a group (i.e gr1) have more items, like 3 different login, close time?

Comment: It is a list "sorted" i added tag gr# just to better understand it the result will be in first example list:
Login 9:00 Pause 9:02 Resume 10:00 Close 15:00

Comment: Shouldn't `ActionSchedule` have another property like `ActionId` which shows which Action they belong to? and you should get that action right?

Comment: Why you think actionschedule need to have actionId if have TaskJob (enum) that perform same job.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is unclear, but I'm going to try and extrapolate.

#### Context

You have a `List<ActionSchedule>`.

```
var actions = new List<ActionSchedule>
{
    new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Login, Start = new TimeSpan(9,0,0) },
    new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Pause, Start = new TimeSpan(9,2,0) },
    new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Resume, Start = new TimeSpan(10,0,0) },
    new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Close, Start = new TimeSpan(15,0,0) },
    new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Login, Start = new TimeSpan(17,0,0) },
    new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Pause, Start = new TimeSpan(18,0,0) },
    new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Resume, Start = new TimeSpan(18,30,0) },
    new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Close, Start = new TimeSpan(21,0,0) },
    new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Login, Start = new TimeSpan(22,0,0) },
    new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Close, Start = new TimeSpan(6,0,0) }
};
```

You want a `List<List<ActionSchedule>>` (or something like that, like `List<ActionScheduleCollection>`) so you can have "groups", let's name it `actionLists`. It will contains all your `ActionSchedule`, splitted into lists ("groups") starting with a `Login` ActionSchedule and ending with `Close` one. The implementation is trivial:

```
var actionLists = new List<List<ActionSchedule>>();
List<ActionSchedule> actionList = null;
foreach (var action in actions)
{
    if (action.Mode == TaskJob.Login)
    {
        actionList = new List<ActionSchedule>();
        actionLists.Add(actionList);
    }

    actionList.Add(action);
}
```

#### Requirement

You want the current "active" group (DateTime.Now is between "active" group's login and closing times), or the group that will be "active" next.

> if datetime now is 14:00 it will give me gr1 list
>
> if datetime now is 16:00 it will give me gr2 list cause gr1 end at 15:00 *(note: even though gr2 starts at 17:00)*

#### Solution

This is more complex than I expected! Moreso with such an inconvenient `ActionSchedule` structure.

Basically, we do a two-step verification to get the current group.
First, we naively check if there's a group which Login time is lesser than current time, and Close time is greater than current time.
If not, we loop through the groups, comparing each to the next, and find the group which Close time is lesser than current time, and which next group's Login time is greather than current time.

It's a bit of a words salad, so here's some code:

```
private static List<ActionSchedule> GetCurrentGroup(List<List<ActionSchedule>> actionLists, TimeSpan now)
{
    var currentGroup = actionLists.SingleOrDefault(actionList => IsActive(actionList, now));

    if (currentGroup == null)
    {
        // Comparing each list with the next to see where 'now' fits for the 'next active group'
        // We assume lists are already ordered by their start time, and that their start/close times
        // don't overlap
        for (int i = 0; i < actionLists.Count; i++)
        {
            // index of the next list; if it's out of bounds, we reset to the first list, index 0
            int j = i + 1;
            if (j >= actionLists.Count)
                j = 0;

            var nextList = actionLists[j];

            var closeFirst = actionLists[i].Single(action => action.Mode == TaskJob.Close).Start;
            var loginLast = nextList.Single(action => action.Mode == TaskJob.Login).Start;

            if (TimeBetween(now, closeFirst, loginLast))
            {
                currentGroup = nextList;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return currentGroup;
}

private static bool IsActive(List<ActionSchedule> actionList, TimeSpan now)
{
    var login = actionList.Single(action => action.Mode == TaskJob.Login).Start;
    var close = actionList.Single(action => action.Mode == TaskJob.Close).Start;
    return TimeBetween(now, login, close);
}

private static bool TimeBetween(TimeSpan now, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
{
    if (start < end)
        return start <= now && now <= end;
    return !(end < now && now < start);
}
```

#### Testing

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var actions = new List<ActionSchedule>
    {
        new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Login, Start = new TimeSpan(9,0,0) },
        new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Pause, Start = new TimeSpan(9,2,0) },
        new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Resume, Start = new TimeSpan(10,0,0) },
        new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Close, Start = new TimeSpan(15,0,0) },
        new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Login, Start = new TimeSpan(17,0,0) },
        new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Pause, Start = new TimeSpan(18,0,0) },
        new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Resume, Start = new TimeSpan(18,30,0) },
        new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Close, Start = new TimeSpan(21,0,0) },
        new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Login, Start = new TimeSpan(22,0,0) },
        new ActionSchedule { Mode = TaskJob.Close, Start = new TimeSpan(6,0,0) }
    };

    var actionLists = new List<List<ActionSchedule>>();
    List<ActionSchedule> actionList = null;
    foreach (var action in actions)
    {
        if (action.Mode == TaskJob.Login)
        {
            actionList = new List<ActionSchedule>();
            actionLists.Add(actionList);
        }

        actionList.Add(action);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Time is 10:00:00");
    PrintGroup(GetCurrentGroup(actionLists, new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0)));

    Console.WriteLine("Time is 14:00:00");
    PrintGroup(GetCurrentGroup(actionLists, new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0)));

    Console.WriteLine("Time is 16:00:00");
    PrintGroup(GetCurrentGroup(actionLists, new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0)));

    Console.WriteLine("Time is 20:00:00");
    PrintGroup(GetCurrentGroup(actionLists, new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0)));

    Console.WriteLine("Time is 23:00:00");
    PrintGroup(GetCurrentGroup(actionLists, new TimeSpan(23, 0, 0)));

    Console.WriteLine("Time is 05:00:00");
    PrintGroup(GetCurrentGroup(actionLists, new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0)));

    Console.WriteLine("Time is 07:00:00");
    PrintGroup(GetCurrentGroup(actionLists, new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0)));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void PrintGroup(List<ActionSchedule> group)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Login: {group.Single(a => a.Mode == TaskJob.Login).Start}, Closing: {group.Single(a => a.Mode == TaskJob.Close).Start}");
}
```